# "CSS background-image: url()" cant find an image that is present with "HTML img src="

Tags: html, css, image, background, http-status-code-404

I would like to set a background image to a div using CSS. 
While I can display the image while using HTML `<img src="/static/img/fon1.jpg">`...
I get a 404 (Not Found) when I try to set the image through CSS:
`style="background-image: url(/static/img/fon1.jpg)"`\

- I have tried different paths like: `../img/fon1.jpg` and many others. Also with and withoud quotes.
- I am certain that the css and the html are linked correctly as I can set the background to a solid color.
- If I use  in html, the css elements find and display the picture as well.

I feel like I should resort to just using `<img>` and rescaling it to fit the window, but I'd like to know what's wrong with the sucker.
Any kind of help / materials / links / jokes are welcome. Thank you if you take your time. All the best!

Folder structure:

```
project
└─static
  └─ img
  |    fon1.jpg
  └─ stylesheet
  |    styles.css
  └─ base.html
```

HTML

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/stylesheet/styles.css">
...
<body>
<div class="background1"></div>
<div class="background2" style="background-image: url('/static/img/fon1.jpg')"></div>
</body>
...
```

CSS

```css
.background1 {
    background-image: url(../img/fon1.jpg);
    height: 960px;
    width: 1280px;
}
.background2 {
    background: red;
    height: 960px;
    width: 1280px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the quotes in your code.

```
.background1 {
  background-image: url('../img/fon1.jpg');
  height: 960px;
  width: 1280px;
}
```

Comment: Hey! I made a mistake in the description, I've actually used different quotes (instead of brackets) and get the same result :(

Comment: Use the brackets and try with quotes. Let me know if it's working

Comment: Thanks Joy for taking your time! I discovered that the background image displays well if i write it in the html like so `<div class="background3" style="background-image: url('img/fon1.jpg')"></div>
` but it's not working if I move the same style into a stylesheet
`.background3 {
    height: 960px;
    width: 1280px;
    background-image: url(img/fon1.jpg)
}`
 (quotes didn't make a difference, worked both ways)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proble lies in JetBrains Webstorm application. I tried the same configur on another application where I was hosting the server, and then the images were found. Currently I was using Webstorms feature to open local HTML file in browser. Seems that it doesnt support GET requests from .css file.

Update:
When referencing static files in Webstorm Live Edit the path should include the project folder. In my case the img would be located at: http://localhost:63342/projectname/static/img/fon1.jpg

Answer (score -1):

I don't know from which file you are trying to access the image. I am assuming, You are trying from `base.html`

you are able to add the image like this.

```
<img src="./img/fon1.jpg">
```

Comment: Hey! I am trying to display background-img through CSS styles.css. As mentioned in the post img src is working, and the question is why background-image URL is not.